# TypeError: Cannot compare dtypes int64 and datetime64[ns]

Tags: pandas, datetime, indexer

I have datime as `df` follows.

```
0    2019-04-09 15:40:00
1    2019-04-09 15:45:00
2    2019-04-09 15:50:00
3    2019-04-09 15:55:00
4    2019-04-09 16:00:00
5    2019-04-09 16:05:00
6    2019-04-09 16:10:00
7    2019-04-09 16:15:00
8    2019-04-09 16:20:00
9    2019-04-09 16:25:00
10   2019-04-09 16:30:00
11   2019-04-09 16:35:00
12   2019-04-09 16:40:00
13   2019-04-09 16:45:00
14   2019-04-09 16:50:00
15   2019-04-09 16:55:00
16   2019-04-09 17:00:00
17   2019-04-09 17:05:00
18   2019-04-09 17:10:00
19   2019-04-09 17:15:00
```

I tried to get the nearest date.

```
result = df.index.get_indexer([pd.to_datetime('2019-04-09 17:01:00')], method='nearest')
```

But it gives the following error.

```
   match = X.index.get_indexer([dt], method='nearest')
  File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3740, in get_indexer
    return self._get_indexer_non_comparable(target, method=method, unique=True)
  File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5990, in _get_indexer_non_comparable
    raise TypeError(f"Cannot compare dtypes {self.dtype} and {other.dtype}")
TypeError: Cannot compare dtypes int64 and datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The datetimes don't appear to be the index here?

Comment: the nearest  one is, `16   2019-04-09 17:00:00`

Comment: Your index is int64. You can't find the nearest indexer based on a datetime, since your index is `0` ... `19`. `2019-04-09 15:40:00` ... `2019-04-09 15:40:00` is not the index.

Comment: @OCa it is `datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BigBen hinted for, [get_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) compares its target argument with the dataframe's *index*. Therefore, provided the time column was already in datetime format, you simply forgot to set your datetime column as index first.

```
df = df.set_index(['DT64'])
df.head()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2019-04-09 15:40:00, 2019-04-09 15:45:00, 2019-04-09 15:50:00, 2019-04-09 15:55:00, 2019-04-09 16:00:00]
```

*(yes, that is an empty dataframe, only index exists)*

Now you can get the indexer: (just reproducing your line here)

```
ix = df.index.get_indexer([pd.to_datetime('2019-04-09 17:01:00')], method='nearest')
ix
array([16], dtype=int64)
```

That has correctly returned the index of the nearest date.

```
df.iloc[ix]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2019-04-09 17:00:00]
```